# Linux configuration settings

Tags: linux, rhel, configuration

Where are the following configuration files located (e.g., Redhat)?

1. network settings (static/DHCP/DNS)
2. timezone
3. proxy for network
4. default language

Comment: In title of your question there is `Linux configuration settings` in content you mention about Red Hat, so the question is - you want to know how it is done in various distributions or specifically in Red Hat? Many of these setting on different distributions will be placed in different places. If you mean _only in Red Hat_: Red Hat Linux (9) that is 8 years old or Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)?

Comment: Should we update the title of this to _Can someone do my homework for me?_

Comment: @Kyle: What's the evidence for homework here?

Comment: @Terry: Please don't ask 4 questions in one. Either ask general questions like "Where are config files stored" or specific ones such as "where are proxy settings in RedHat 6". Also, always explain in your questions what attempts yo have made to answer the question yourself and how they turned out.

Comment: @Caleb:  A specific list of files to look for with no background on why someone would want to know just smells awfully "homeworkey" to me.  I suppose there's a chance he just has a new Linux box and no idea how to configure it.

Comment: @Kyle "I suppose there's a chance he just has a new Linux box and no idea how to configure it" -- that seems wildly more likely

Comment: @Michael - I guess I'm just either more paranoid or more cynical than you.  Perhaps both.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `/etc` directory. All the config files for your entire system should be there with quite logical names like 'timezone'. Some of the subdirectories are also important such as `/etc/sysconfig/` so be sure to browse that. The network stuff is also usually buried in there in a folder called 'interfaces' with one config file per interface.